# Regarding Boolean logic in Solr

Tags: solr, search-engine, boolean-logic

I have a Solr index with a year field, I can query all results within a range of years using the following query which works fine

```
*:* AND year:[1934 TO 1950]
```

How would I incorporate the AND operator so I can search for results in a number of selected years, eg. results for year 1930 AND year 1950 only. I tried something like:

```
*:* AND year:1934 AND year:1950
```

the above query displays no results.

Comment: I should also mention '*:* AND year:1934' displays the correct number of results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*:* AND (year:1934 OR year:1950)
```

Your's does not display a result because there can be no match in *both* years (but that's what what the expression says).

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need to get `*:* AND year:[1934 TO 1950]`, just `year:[1934 TO 1950]` is enough.
2. Unless `year` is a multivalued field you probably want `year:1934 OR year:1950`